# Dynamic Programming Solution for TSP in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been trying to implement Dynamic Programming solution for TSP [(Travelling Salesperson Problem)](http://wiki.c2.com/?TravelingSalesmanProblem) in C++. My code compiles but when I try to run the object file the program stops working and I am forced to close it.

Here is the code:

```
int tsp(std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix) {

   int n = matrix[0].size();
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> A;  // Vertex, Set-Size
   std::set<int> S;

   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       S.insert(i);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if(S.size() == 2) {
           A[i][2] = matrix[1][i];
       }
       else if(S.size() > 2) {
           std::set<int>::iterator it;
           for(it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); ++it) {
               int s = S.size();
               S.erase(i);
               int sd = S.size();
               int k = *it;
               if((k != i) && (k != 1) && (A[i][s] > (matrix[k][i] + A[k][sd]))) {
                   A[i][s] = matrix[k][i] + A[k][sd];
               }
           }
       }
   }

   return A[1][n];
}
```

Can someone please point out what mistake I am making.

Comment: `A` is *empty*, any indexing into it will be *out of bounds*.

Comment: So what have you learned from stepping through the code under the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But it gives the same error even if i initialize elements of A to arbitrarily large values.

Comment: And how about `A[i]`? That's a vector as well, did you make sure it has enough elements?

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results, and also  to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill or [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) a `std::vector` before calling `operator[int]` on it. A vector is basically an array that holds its size. So any out of bound access will cause a segmentation fault in runtime (if you are lucky) or will corrupt your memory.

You have a vector of vectors here, so you will need to iterate over two ranges and fill (or resize) vectors properly:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A;  // Vertex, Set-Size
for(int i=size; i>0; --i)
   A.push_back(std::vector<int>);
for(int i=size; i>0; --i)
   for(int j=size; j>0; --j)
     A[i][j] = 0;
```

Even better:

```
A.resize(size);
for(auto& v : a)        // (since you already have c++11)
  v.resize(size, val);  // fill with val
```